# Solaris - What is it good for?

Tags: solaris

I'm looking to find some articles/literature on Solaris other than just Wikipedia. In particular, how it differs from all of the other unix-like systems. Does anybody use Solaris, and if so, why? I know it isn't a particularly commonly used OS, so I'm just wondering why that is.

Comment: For running on SPARCstations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solaris is not a Unix-like / Linux system. It's a true Unix system -- according to the [Single Unix Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification), anyway, along with AIX and OS X.

This is a big topic, but I'd say the biggest difference between them is the fact that Linux (kernel) is **completely** open source, whereas Solaris is not. Oracle also provides vendor level support for the OS.

Chris O brings up a good point also. If you're running a Sun SPARC architecture (which is pretty uncommon these days), you're likely going to have better support with Solaris as opposed to any Linux distribution.

There's a somewhat lengthy article on this that you may find worth reading. [Check it out here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/solaris-linux-app-139382.html)

Comment: That link looks really awesome, thanks a lot!

Comment: @KepaniHaole you said that is pretty uncommon using Sun SPARC architecture these days, but I heard somewhere most of FORTUNE 500 companies run Solaris. So they are running Solaris on something other than SPARC architecture or your answer is meant in a way that not many companies run Solaris?

Comment: Now that it is 2018, can you update this article with more info about how common solaris is?